# Patent Still Active?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US20090293169](https://www.google.com/patents/US20090293169)

So this is provisional every become a full patent?  If so is it still active?

Answer (score 0):

This is neither a provisional nor a patent. It is a patent application and its status is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" so it seems unlikely to ever become a full patent. You can check this for yourself by looking at the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site and entering 20090293169 and selecting "Publication Number". From that site you can see all the communications between the inventor's agent and the examiner.